# C# entity framework better function or calculated property in model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello I'm writing a little C# web app using asp.net core 1.1 MVC with EF (code first)

I want to know what is the best engineering choice.
Let's assume that I have a class and I need to calculate something using one or more related properties; let's make an example:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<B> Bs { get; set; }    

    public int GetMaxB()
    {
        return Bs.Max( b => b.Num ); /*simple example, can be more complex */
    }
}

class B
{    
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int Num { get; set; } 
}
```

So, for `GetMaxB()` (let's think about a more complex function, not only one line) what is the best option?

- a function in the model class
- a generated (NotMapped) property in the model class
- a function in controller
- other

Comment: If this is just for your view, create a view model and populate that.

Comment: Depends... You can't always assume that `Bs` is loaded or *can be loaded* lazily when you need them.

Comment: Also, maybe only some portion of the B's are loaded, which then could be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic can be a part of VM, you may not want to have it mix with the Model, which should be a pure class with properties.

Comment: yes with decorator! seem a good choice ex:

class AViewModel {
public A a {get; private set;}
public AViewModel(A a){ this.a= a; }
public int GetMaxB() { /*blah */ }
}

Comment: what about extension methods? VM is not cool if I want to make queries on calculated properties

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon situations and nature of property.

A calculated property like DiscountValue (which depend few other properties) be part of Model class.

If use of a GetMaxB() is less frequent then it can be a function in Model.

If GetMaxB() is only reason for which collection class is used in Class A, then you can think separate out provided use is not frequent.